# Using leaflets to load circle coordinates from a json file/Using data retrieved from a circle object

Tags: javascript

Im ' trying to reproduce the code from the example http://www.d3noob.org/2014/03/leaflet-map-with-d3js-elements-that-are.html,

but it doesn't load the file (i have tried loading the file from my pc and from the website) circles.js, here is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/U2z5G/

in my computer i have this line:

```
d3.json("circles.js", function(collection)
```

Edit:That helped, thank you, now i have this issue, i put some circles over the map, when an user click that area a function should return a value with the id of that area, but seem like Javascript doesn´t store for to long in a local/global variable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet GeoJSON Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link  rel="stylesheet"    href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css"   />
    <style>
        #map {
            width: 800px;
            height: 500px;
        }

        .info {
            padding: 6px 8px;
            font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            background: white;
            background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
            box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        .info h4 {
            margin: 0 0 5px;
            color: #777;
        }

        .legend {
            text-align: left;
            line-height: 18px;
            color: #555;
        }
        .legend i {
            width: 18px;
            height: 18px;
            float: left;
            margin-right: 8px;
            opacity: 0.7;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
function changetext(id)
{
id.innerHTML=idEdo;
}
</script>
    </head>
<body>
<center>
    <div id="map" style="width: 700px; height: 500px"></div>
</center>
    <script src="circles.json" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script
        src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js">
    </script>

    <script>

var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(new L.LatLng(49.5, -11.3), new L.LatLng(61.2, 2.5));

var idEdo;  
var map = L.map('map').setView([23.906, -102.534], 5);
        L.tileLayer("http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
            minZoom: 5,
            maxZoom: 6,
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>'
        }).addTo(map);

    map.setMaxBounds([
    [32.69487, -117.33398],
    [14.0087, -87.09961]
]);
    var info = L.control();

        info.onAdd = function (map) {
            this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
            this.update();
            return this._div;
        };

        info.update = function (cn,tmp) {


        this._div.innerHTML = cn ;  

        };

        info.addTo(map);

        function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

        var popupContent = feature.id + " >> ";
        var contenido = '<h4>Oficinas ALAF</h4>';
        var tmp;

            if (feature.properties && feature.properties.nombre) {

             var  c = String(feature.properties.sede);
             var tmp = c.split(",");
            popupContent += feature.properties.nombre ; 

            info.update(contenido); 

            //idEdo =   parseInt(feature.id),10);   
            }



        layer.bindPopup(popupContent);

        }

        L.geoJson([estados], {

            style: function (feature) {
                return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
            },

            onEachFeature: onEachFeature,

            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                    radius: 7.5,
                    fillColor: "#ff0000",
                    color: "#ff0022",
                    weight: 1,
                    opacity: 0.5,
                    fillOpacity: 0.6
                });
            }
        }).addTo(map);




    </script>
    <h1 onclick="changetext(this)">Click on this text!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and this the file circles.json:

```
var estados = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -111.88477,25.87899
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Baja California Sur",
            "sede": [ "sede 1", "sede 2", "sede 3" ]
        },
        "id": 51
    },
    {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -115.15869, 30.33495
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Baja California",
            "sede": [ "sede 11", "sede 21", "sede 31" ]
        },
        "id": 52
    },
    {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
               -110.91797, 29.91685 
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Sonora"
        },
        "id": 54
    },
    {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                 -106.21582, 29.15216
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Chihuahua"
        },
        "id": 55
    },
    {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
               -102.04102, 27.76133
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Coahuila"
        },
        "id": 57
    },
    {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
               -99.8877,25.64153
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Nuevo León"
        },
        "id": 58
    },
    {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
               -98.61328,24.32708
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Tamaulipas"
        },
        "id": 74
    },

     {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -107.44629,24.68695
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Sinaloa"
        },
        "id": 00
    },

    {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -104.89746, 24.96614
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Durango"
        },
        "id": 00
    },

    {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
               -103.00781,23.13026
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Zacatecas"
        },
        "id": 00
    },

        {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -100.99731,22.26876
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "San Luis Potosi"
        },
        "id": 00
    },

    {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -88.90137,20.7972
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Yucatan"
        },
        "id": 00
    },

    {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
               -88.33008,19.14517
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Quintana Roo"
        },
        "id": 00
    },


    {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
               -90.52734,19.18668
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Campeche"
        },
        "id": 00
    },

        {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
               -92.72461,18.22935
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Tabasco"
        },
        "id": 00
    },

        {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -92.59277,16.46769
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Chiapas"
        },
        "id": 00
    },
        {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -96.45996,16.80454
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Oaxaca"
        },
        "id": 00
    },
        {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
               -99.8877,17.43451
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Guerrero"
        },
        "id": 00
    }
    ,
        {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
               -104.0625,19.06212
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Colima"
        },
        "id": 00
    }
    ,
        {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
             -104.10645,20.34463
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Jalisco"
        },
        "id": 00
    }
    ,
        {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -101.95312,19.26967
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Michoacan"
        },
        "id": 00
    }
    ,
        {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
               -104.98535,21.90228 
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Nayarait"
        },
        "id": 00
    }
    ,
        {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
               -102.44751,22.01436
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Aguascalientes"
        },
        "id": 00
    }
    ,
        {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
               -100.99731,21.00247
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Guanajuato"
        },
        "id": 00
    }
    ,
        {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
             -99.85474,20.84855
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Querétaro"
        },
        "id": 00
    }
    ,
        {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
            -98.9978,20.52993
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Hidalgo"
        },
        "id": 00
    }
    ,
        {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -99.68994,19.48731
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Estado de México"
        },
        "id": 00
    }
    ,
        {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -99.03076,18.76071
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Morelos"
        },
        "id": 00
    }
    ,
        {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -98.06396,18.83352, 
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Puebla"
        },
        "id": 00
    }
    ,
        {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -98.1958,19.42515
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Tlaxcala"
        },
        "id": 00
    }
    ,
        {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
           -96.5918,19.34224
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Veracruz"
        },
        "id": 00
    }
    ,
        {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -99.14062,19.43292
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "nombre": "Distrito Federal"
        },
        "id": 00
    }


]
```

};

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running into a Cross Domain Request issue when requesting the json from a remote server.

If you look at your debugging tools when you load your page (or the jsfiddle page) you'll see the `No Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error in your cosole.

One solution would be to set up a proxy server to get around this...but...

An easier solution would be to do the following:

1. Copy the actual contents of the [circle.json file](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/raw/9267535/circles.json) you're trying to load,
2. Paste that content into a local document on your file system
3. Refer to the local file in your script tag

Note:  If you'd like to learn more about the Cross Domain Request issue, google '[cross domain requests](https://www.google.com/search?q=cross+domain+requests++&oq=cross+domain+requests++&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3703j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)' or '[cors](https://www.google.com/search?q=cors&oq=cors&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j69i61j69i60.479j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)'. Or read [this article on cross domain ajax requests](http://www.d-mueller.de/blog/cross-domain-ajax-guide/) or [this wikipedia page on Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Good times...

AFTER EDIT:
Just saw your edit to the question.  Changing the extension from .json to .js won't solve the problem (the json won't be recognized as valid javascript unless you modify it somewhat (like assign it to a variable), at which point the D3 object will no longer be able to recognize it as json...).

Yet another solution would be to paste the json directly into your javascript...

[Here's a working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Zw6d/2/) that does just that.